# ASP.NET Entity Framework LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, linq

I am basically trying to an "Archives" of dates grouped by Month and Year. However my problem is the dates in the database are strings...not my choice.

Here is my code to get that list of date groups

```
var dates = dbBlog.Data
                .GroupBy(o => new
                {
                    Month = Convert.ToDateTime(o.date).Month,
                    Year = Convert.ToDateTime(o.date).Year
                })
                .Select(g => new BlogArchiveClass
                {
                    Month = g.Key.Month,
                    Year = g.Key.Year,
                    Total = g.Count()
                })
                .OrderByDescending(a => a.Year)
                .ThenByDescending(a => a.Month)
                .ToList();
```

But when I use it, I get this error:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ToDateTime(System.String)
```

How would I be able to accomplish what I am doing with string dates from the database?

Comment: Do everything that's in your power to get the database design right. Don't settle with "impossible". Dates as string will be a continuous pain in the neck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the format of your string then you can probably do something that looks like this :

```
var dates = dbBlog.Data
            Select(d => new 
            {
                 Month = d.Month.Substring(....),
                 Year  = d.Year.Substring(....)
            })
            .GroupBy(o => new { o.Month,o.Year})
            .Select(g => new BlogArchiveClass
            {
                Month = g.Key.Month,
                Year = g.Key.Year,
                Total = g.Count()
            })
            .OrderByDescending(a => a.Year)
            .ThenByDescending(a => a.Month)
            .ToList();
```

Comment: I dont get it....what replaces `....` Also d does not contain Month or Year (my class doesn't contain them)

Comment: @user979331 I think he had in mind `o.Date`. And `...` is `start, length` of the corresponding date parts inside the string (when the format is fixed, you can calculate them). If the format is not fixed, you are out of luck.

Comment: That's exactly what I meant thank you. Indeed, if you date format is fixed you can choose to extract the value of Month and year using substring https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Alternatively if the target db is SqlServer only, you could try [`SqlFunctions.DateName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487163(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The only part I dont understand is where do i put o.Date?

Comment: you don't need o.date anymore, it has been split in two properties Month and Year in the 1st Select Statement in order to be able to group by on the following statement. From what I understood from you original query you are only required to return month\year\Count of post for this given month \ year